# Can I use inventory data from a web service within a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I currently run my playbooks via

```
# ansible-playbook -i myscript.py myplaybook.yaml
```

where `myscript.py` generates the relevant host information (per the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html)) and `myplaybook.py` starts with

```
---
- hosts: all
(...)
```

This works fine.

I now would like to

- receive the inventory via a web service: include within the playbook a [call to the web service](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) and receive the inventory in the appropriate format, whatever it is (I control the web service)
- as well as make use of this inventory directly within the playbook, without the `-i` parameter, having the `host: all` directive understand that it is supposed to use it.

**Is this something which is possible in ansible?** I am under the impression that the inventory is needed at the start of the playbook (= that it cannot be generated within the playbook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your inventory dynamically with `add_host` module.
Start with something like this and modify it to your needs:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host: name={{item}} group=hosts_from_webservice
      with_url: https://mywebservice/host_list_as_simple_strings
      # in this example web service should return one ip/hostname by line:
      # 10.1.1.1
      # 10.1.1.2
      # 10.1.1.3

    - add_host: name={{(item | from_json).host}} group=hosts_from_webservice description={{(item | from_json).desc}}
      with_url: https://mywebservice/host_list_as_json_strings
      # in this example web service should return JSON object on every line:
      # {"host":"10.1.1.1","desc":"hello"}
      # {"host":"10.1.1.2","desc":"world"}
      # {"host":"10.1.1.3","desc":"test"}

- hosts: hosts_from_webservice
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="I'm a host from webservice"
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you know what is the data structure expected to be received from the web service? The only doc about `with_url` is in ["More Lookups"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups) and merely states that the command exists. I expect it to be some kind of list so that `{{item}}`can iterate over it but fail to understand what exactly should be provided (it is not the JSON form the dynamic inventory definition, it looks like it should be something which is, as I mentioned, iterable over I think).

Comment: Specifically, I get the following error: "`creating host via 'add_host': hostname={'hosts': ['10.11.2.16', '10.11.2.4', '10.11.2.5', '10.11.2.15', '10.11.2.6']}
Unexpected Exception: unhashable type: 'dict'
`and I tried multiple data structures (the ones visible after`hostname=`): lists, dicts, etc. - the error is that they are all unhashable (I expect at that point that `hostname=` should have one hostname passed, iterated over teh response of the web service - which I do not know how to structure.

Comment: @WoJ i've updated my answer with examples. `with_url` iterates over lines in http response – it is general lookup plugin and can be used with any tasks, not just with add_host.