# howto conditionally define hosts for a play in Ansible

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I am running a set of tasks on multiple sets of nodes.
I have a dedicated INI file for each set of node with groups defined.

For one of the groups, there is one node ('nfs_server') for which I want to make an exception.
I have created a playbook with conditionally defined hosts like:

```
  hosts: "{{ nfs_server if monitoring_enabled else '' }}"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: var=monitoring_enabled
    - name: install monitoring
      when: monitoring_enabled
      include: extras/setup_monitoring.yml
```

Where I tried to define the variable in either the inventory, or the group_vars file, but I alwasy get the error that the variable is not defined:

`ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'monitoring_enabled' is undefined`.

When I change the hosts (temporarily) to 'all', the run completes, and I see that the variable is properly evaluated:

`ok: [master1] => { "monitoring_enabled": "false" }`

WA1: I did find an imho rather ugly workaround by defining an additional group in my inventory using the 'children' statement. This group must then be defined with the proper nodes for all my
servers where I want to add the extra monitoring, and empty in the inventory for the exceptional set.

WA2: I also found a workaround in [Can I use inventory data from a web service within a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630085/can-i-use-inventory-data-from-a-web-service-within-a-playbook/38631923#38631923) where the 'add_host' is used to create a dynamic group. I've been able to make this work, but again not very clean.

**question:** Is there an easier way to define the set of hosts for a play conditionally?

Strong preference would be such that I can have also a default value for the boolean, such that I do not need to define it everywhere.

thx, M.

Comment: No. There is no easier way. A dynamic group by *add_host* is the only option inside a playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your finding

> *... defining an additional group in my inventory using the 'children'
> statement. This group must then be defined with the proper nodes for
> all my servers ...*

I wouldn't consider that as a workaround. If your infrastructure is somehow structured your mentioned approach would have some advantages. Let's assume your inventory looks like

```ini
[infra:children]
prod
qa
dev

webserver
database

[infra:vars]
# No global variables yet

[prod:children]
webserver_prod
database_prod

[qa:children]
webserver_qa
database_qa

[dev:children]
webserver_dev
database_dev

# Logical services nodes

[webserver:children]
webserver_prod
webserver_qa
webserver_dev

[database:children]
database_prod
database_qa
database_dev

# List of all hosts

# [prod:children]

[webserver_prod]
web.prod.example.com

[database_prod]
primary.prod.example.com
secondary.prod.example.com

# [qa:children]

[webserver_qa]
web.qa.example.com

[database_qa]
primary.qa.example.com
secondary.qa.example.com

# [dev:children]

[webserver_dev]
web.dev.example.com

[database_dev]
primary.dev.example.com
secondary.dev.example.com
```

it is than possible to apply playbooks, tasks, etc. just to certain nodes in that graph like

```bash
ansible-inventory dev --graph
ansible-inventory database_dev --graph
...
```

All depdends on the structure of the inventory but makes it easier afterwards.

Comment: I assume that by "I wouldn't consider that as a workaround" you mean that this is the best solution? Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: @Monger39, regarding "_you mean that this is the best solution_" it was for me and my environment, few 100 servers, the simplest and least complex approach I could find. Since I can apply any role I like, like antivirus, security scan, monitoring, backup, audit, etc, to any hosts, or group or datacenter, or net segment just by naming it.